# XSLT how to contain only number in a string value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

How can I get only number in a string value? I tried this function but it is not working. What is a possible problem?

**Original file:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ns0:Request xmlns:ns0="http://ABS.NM.B">
        <TRANSACTION>
          <LREF>SUBIS     70055593</LREF>
        </TRANSACTION>
    </ns0:Request>
```

**XSLT:**

```
    <xsl:template match="TRANSACTION" >
     <Transaction reference="{LREF}" >
        <xsl:attribute name="reference">
         <xsl:value-of select="replace($input, '.*[^.\d](.*)$', '$1')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </Transaction>
    </xsl:template>
```

**Result:**

```
     <Transaction reference="70055593">
     </Transaction>
```

Comment: In your XSLT, change <xsl:variable name="input" select="CLREF"/> to <xsl:variable name="input" select="LREF"/> (CLREF to LREF), see input XML, LREF element content needs to set in variable.

Comment: Below XSLT should be updated under your post, not in my post.

Answer (score 2):

Your code almost correct, but variable only needs to set as given below.

```
<xsl:template match="TRANSACTION" >
 <xsl:variable name="input" select="LREF"/>
  <Transaction reference="{LREF}" >
    <xsl:attribute name="reference">
     <xsl:value-of select="replace($input, '.*[^.\d](.*)$', '$1')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
 </Transaction>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Have you declared variable as shown in my post? I tried like that only, I got the result.

Comment: yes i did declare variable. i am gonna update my post so you can see what is my xslt like okay